ServiceStack.Text not handling JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)
I am trying to serialize the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails class and it has JsonIgnore with conditionals on its properties like Title
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
[JsonPropertyOrder(-4)]
[JsonPropertyName("title")]
public string? Title { get; set; }

When I use ServiceStack.Text to serialize this object title is omited even though it is not null has a valid string in it. Is there a way to get ServiceStack.Text to respect these conditionals or just ignore JsonIgnore as I use IgnoreDataMember to suppress a field when serializing. Hoping to not have to write a custom serializer for this type...
Edit:
Looks like you can suppress JsonIgnore like this
JsConfig.IgnoreAttributesNamed = ["JsonIgnore"];

However that then also makes IgnoreDataMember stop working :( so that really isn't a solution because then you can't suppress anything...

You need to use fully qualified name of the attribute in order for it to work:
JsConfig.IgnoreAttributesNamed = ["System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreAttribute"];

And also make sure to have not overwritten this behavior:
JsConfig.Init(new Config { IncludeNullValues = false });

which is default setup (just in case you have overwritten it).

setting IgnoreAttributesNamed to what you have makes the property show up, but then [IgnoreDataMember] also stops working even though that is not defined in the IgnoreAttributesNamed field.
